# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 ERROR for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-sql

My Code is below. It is giving an error in Android Studio. Anyone please help me. My PHP code is OK but why is it giving this error?

**Register.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et_name, et_number;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
        et_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numbertxt);

    }

    public void userReg(View view){

        String names = et_name.getText().toString();
        String numbers = et_number.getText().toString();

        String method = "register";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,names,numbers);
        finish();


    }
}
```

**And My Background.java Code is**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){

        this.ctx = ctx;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://192.168.1.2/logins/register.php";
        String method = params[0];
        if(method.equals("register")){

            String name = params[1];
            String number = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("names","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("numbers","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(number,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream IS = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Registration Success...";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**And my Androidmainfest.xml is**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**Android Studio Error is :**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                     Process: com.example.smtanverhossain.myphpmysqlapplication, PID: 5445
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast
>   to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
>                         at com.example.smtanverhossain.myphpmysqlapplication.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:46)
>                         at com.example.smtanverhossain.myphpmysqlapplication.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:19)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explained in the log: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

This means you can't cast to `HttpsURLConnection` at this line:

```
HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

The reason for this is because your URL uses `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`. When you call `url.openConnection()` with `HTTP`, it returns a `HttpURLConnection` and same applies for `HTTPS`. This is stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection).

The solution should be to replace all `HttpsURLConnection` with `HttpURLConnection` and remove the cast to `HttpsURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Tohu might resolve your cast error, something that I want to bring to your sight, you are passing the context of the activity, to the asynktask,  that you are destroying by calling `finish()` , this might give you a error when you to show toast with activity context. 
So make sure you give a valid context,like:-.

```
getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: Check your android version,  you must include the following declaration within the element of AndroidManifest.xml.   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library